# Как сделать кнопки (Bootstrap)

Tags: java, html, веб-программирование, bootstrap, spring

У меня выводит вот такую таблицу, я хочу чтобы за место Add Student, delete, edit были красивые кнопки. Я попробовал но не получается((
Как можно реализовать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

All Student JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>All Users</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addStudent">Add Student</a>
    <br>
    <h3>List of all users</h3>
    ${message}
    <br>
    <br>
    <table border="1px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>


                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${student.name}</td>
                    <td>${student.surname}</td>


                    <td><a
                        href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editStudent/${student.id}">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a
                        href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteStudent/${student.id}">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>


    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>All Users</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addStudent">Add Student</a>
    <br>
    <h3>List of all users</h3>
    ${message}
    <br>
    <br>
    <table border="1px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>


                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${student.name}</td>
                    <td>${student.surname}</td>


                    <td><a
                        href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editStudent/${student.id}"><button type="button">Edit</button></a></td>
                    <td><a
                        href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteStudent/${student.id}"><button type="button">Delete</button></a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>


    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

На основе вашего кода

Comment: Это через Бутстрап?

Comment: @СтивГейтс  Bootstrap - ничто иное как CSS, это вы должны написать сами как вам угоднее. Я добавил в ваш код лишь вместе ссылки, кнопки. Нажмите на "Выполнить код" и посмотрите. Если точнее, подключаете стиль Bootstrap и вписываете в саму кнопку стиль - пример тут https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/

Comment: Спасибо вам все равно) просто мне нужно через бутстрап)

Comment: @СтивГейтс обновил коммент - подключить Bootstrap на RU.Stackoverflow не могу, поэтому смотрите пример по ссылке.